# Getting "Index was outside of bounds of the Array"

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, arraylist

I am getting the error, and not sure how to fix it. When I change the SQL command to another query, it seems to work (with the same amount of data, 10 rows). Ideas? Note: I am aware I should be using parameters in my SQL command, i am just testing.

```
SqlCommand getLabsCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT labGrade FROM labStudent WHERE studentID = '"+Label1.Text+"' ");
    getLabsCommand.Connection = conn;

    ArrayList alMakers = new ArrayList();

    conn.Open();

    SqlDataReader dr = getLabsCommand.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            //alMakers.Add(dr.GetString(1));
            alMakers.Add(dr.GetInt32(1));

        }
    }
    string[] labsList = (string[])alMakers.ToArray(typeof(string));
    for(int i = 0; i < alMakers.Count; i++)
    {
        TextBox labs = new TextBox();
        labs.ID = "lab" + i; 
        form1.Controls.Add(labs);

        labs.Text = labsList.GetValue(i).ToString();
    }
    dr.Close();
    conn.Close();
}
```

The function above should be putting these values in each textbox.
25
25
25
25
20
22
25
10
15
16

Comment: Where are you getting the error?

Comment: alMakers.Add(dr.GetInt32(1));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only selecting one column (`SELECT labGrade FROM...`); indexing is 0-based, so only `GetInt32(0)` is defined. `GetInt32(1)` refers to the *second* column (the first column is index 0, second column is index 1, etc). You probably want:

```
alMakers.Add(dr.GetInt32(0));
```

This type of thing is where tools like [dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/) shine, btw:

```
var alMakers = conn.Query<int>(
    "SELECT labGrade FROM labStudent WHERE studentID = @id",
    new { id = Label1.Text }).AsList();
```

Comment: Ah, forgot that array indexing starts at 0.. Thanks!